# SQL query to convert integer into date and find difference in number of months

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, integer

I have 2 numbers(Integers) - 20210501 & 20210101 where the first 4 digits represent Year, next 2 digits represent Months and the last 2 digits represent Day. I want to write a SQL query to convert these integers to date and then find the difference in months between the 2 dates

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: And what have you tried? Why isn't it working? Converting values isn't a particularly difficult task in any RDBMS.

Comment: Check out this  for better understanding : https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-date-format-overview-datediff-sql-function-dateadd-sql-function-and-more/

Comment: Hi @Chanandlerbong please check my answer below and let me know if any questions.

Answer (score 1):

At first convert varchar to date format and get month diff

-- SQL SERVER

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, CONVERT(varchar, CAST('20210101' AS DATE), 23), CONVERT(varchar, CAST('20210501' AS DATE), 23)) month_diff
```

Alternate way

-- SQL SERVER

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, CAST(CONVERT(varchar, CAST('20210101' AS DATE), 23) AS date), CAST(CONVERT(varchar, CAST('20210501' AS DATE), 23) AS date)) month_diff
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two integers are conveniently in the right format for dates.  So, you can convert to a string, then to a date and use `datediff()`:

```
select datediff(month,
                convert(date, convert(varchar(255), @val1)),
                convert(date, convert(varchar(255), @val2))
               )
```